# How can I bind a key to M-x C-r (isearch extended command)?

Tags: key-bindings, minibuffer, isearch

I am a fiend for `C-r` (isearch-backward), and I often will enter the minibuffer with `M-x` (execute-extended-command), then use `C-r` to search for a previous command. I'd like to bind a key that drops me into the minibuffer to read an extended command and automatically activates isearch-backward, but I'm not sure how to write such a function.

Comment: By default, `C-r` after `M-x` searches backward in the minibuffer. It does not "*search for a previous command*". Perhaps you mean `M-r`? Or perhaps you have something in your init file that makes Emacs behavior different in this regard? (If so, specify it as part of your question.)

Comment: @Drew For me, with `emacs -q`, `C-r` in the `M-x` prompt does search through command history. I am using emacs 24.3 on this computer, so maybe it's something that changed in recent versions?

Comment: @T.Verron: Not here, not on MS Windows. Not with Emacs 20, 22, 23, 24, or 25, including 24.3. Here, `C-r` after `M-x` runs Isearch backward.

Comment: @T.Verron: I take that back. I see now, from (emacs) [Isearch Minibuffer](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Isearch-Minibuffer.html) (and it's true), that if `C-r`, which *is* backward Isearch **fails** when searching the minibuffer text backward, then it searches backward through the input history (likewise, for `C-s`). `M-r` just immediately searches backward through the history.

Comment: @Drew I see, I was indeed testing it (and that's probably what the OP does too) with an empty minibuffer, so that the regular search certainly fails.

Comment: @T.Verron: Yeah. And I probably knew about the `C-r` failure fallback to navigating the input history long ago, but forgot it. (I don't even use `M-r`, because I use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles), which has much [better ways](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_History_Enhancements) to access input history.

Comment: @T.Verron @Drew Indeed, I was in the habit of using `C-r` in an empty minibuffer, so I didn't even know about `M-r`. As so often happens with Emacs, I set out to learn one thing and ended up learning two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help:

```el
(defun my-M-x (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (minibuffer-with-setup-hook
      (lambda () (call-interactively #'previous-matching-history-element))
    (execute-extended-command arg)))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'my-M-x)
```